# Using reference with array_walk and arrow function

Tags: php

I am not sure how to increase my `email_actions` in this snippet:

```
$email_actions = 0;
array_walk(
    $steps,
    fn($step): int => !empty($step['settings']['type']) &&
                      $step['settings']['type'] === self::FLOWS_EMAIL_TYPE_ACTION
                          ? $email_actions++
                          : false
);
dd($email_actions);
```

I get 0 as result when it should be 2. Tried to pass the variable by reference like:
`fn($step, &$email_actions)` but is obviously not the right approach.

Comment: Never tried with arrow functions but I think it needs to be `fn($step) use (&$email_actions) : int =>`?

Comment: @nice_dev Tried this one as well. Didn't work. In fact i really don't see and option to do it with `fn`.

Comment: @nice_dev `fn()` is supposed to bring the outer variables. `fn($foo) => $foo + $bar;` is equivalent to `function($foo) use ($bar) { ... }`

Comment: I'd never understand why use array_walk where a simple foreach would do. Given you have a hard time understanding how this code works right now means you will have absolutely no idea on that in a couple months. Why someone would voluntarily obfuscate their own code is beyond my understanding

Comment: @Cid Makes sense. Never digged much into arrow ones.

Comment: @TomaTomov To answer your question, it ain't possible. Looks like we need to write an email to NikiC :p

Answer (score 2):

`fn` copies the variables that are automatically *injected*.

From [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) (check example 4) :

> Arrow functions use by-value variable binding. This is roughly
> equivalent to performing a use($x) for every variable $x used inside
> the arrow function. A by-value binding means that it is not possible
> to modify any values from the outer scope. Anonymous functions can be
> used instead for by-ref bindings.

If you want to have a write access (a reference), you might need to use the *old* syntax :

```
$email_actions = 0;
array_walk(
    $steps,
    function($step) use (&$email_actions) : int
    {
        return !empty($step['settings']['type']) &&
               $step['settings']['type'] === self::FLOWS_EMAIL_TYPE_ACTION
                   ? $email_actions++
                   : false;
    }
);
dd($email_actions);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to get single value after iterating through all array

```php
$email_actions = array_reduce(
    $steps,
    function ($carry, $step) {
        if ($step['settings']['type'] === self::FLOWS_EMAIL_TYPE_ACTION) {
            $carry++;
        }
        
        return $carry;
    },
    0
);
```

---

If you *really* need to use arrow functions:

```php
$email_actions = array_count(
    array_filter($steps, fn ($step) => $step['settings']['type'] === self::FLOWS_EMAIL_TYPE_ACTION)
);
```

Comment: It is about the `fn` syntax mostly. How can I use reference with it.

Comment: @TomaTomov You can't do that with arrow functions, does not seem like you are using functions as they are intended to be used.

Comment: @TomaTomov Check updated answer with use of arrow function. But you still can't modify outside scope variables.